# How data can shown in datagridview of selected date from date time picker?

Tags: c#

I have taken display button and code is:-

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
        DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.Now;
        String query = "SELECT sno,currDate,WtrNm,Type,No FROM WtrTblAllot WHERE currDate = @SelectedDate";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedDate", selectedDate);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dgvWtrAllot.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

problem is it shows the datagrid view on click but not show the  selected date data.

coding  area of datetimepicker:-

```
private void dtTmPkrWtr_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: "problem is it shows the datagrid view on click but not show the selected date data." I am not sure what this means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question, not sure what your problem is

Comment: @lc. not showing the data... it shows only database header(eg. sno. , currdate......)

Comment: @V4Vendetta not showing the data... it shows only database header(eg. sno. , currdate......)

Comment: Are you sure there are actual records with a value of `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: There can't be rows with DateTime.Now, use `DateTime selectedDate = dtTmPkrWtr.Value;`

Comment: @lc. when i am checking database table it shows the format of (currDate-'2013-09-05 13:03:10.983') but in date time picker the format is 05/09/2013.. so can you help me....

Comment: What is the data type of `currDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you have method to load the data

```
private void dtTmPkrWtr_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
       LoadGridData(dateTimePicker1.Value);
}

private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
       LoadGridData(DateTime.Now);     
}

private void LoadGridData(DateTime selectedDate)
{
    String query = "SELECT sno,currDate,WtrNm,Type,No FROM WtrTblAllot WHERE currDate = @SelectedDate";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedDate", dateTimePicker1.Value);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    dgvWtrAllot.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: thanx @Damith!!!! your code is working but not showing the data... it shows only database header(eg. sno. , currdate......)

Comment: Yes, that's because you are using the btnDisplay Click event which asks for rows with DateTime.Now, there can't actually be rows with DateTime.Now value, use only the dtTmPkrWtr ValueChanged event or use my solution.

Comment: @trippino when i am checking database table it shows the format of (currDate-'2013-09-05 13:03:10.983') but in date time piker the format is 05/09/2013.. so can you help me....

Comment: @Damith when i am checking database table it shows the format of (currDate-'2013-09-05 13:03:10.983') but in date time picker the format is 05/09/2013.. so can you help me....

Comment: This is only a matter of visualization, if you keep use SqlParameters you shouldn't have problems. I suggest you to NOT store also milliseconds, otherwise your query will (almost) never returns rows

Answer (score 0):

You are using `DateTime.Now` and not the selected value of the `DateTimePicker`, try this:

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime selectedDate = dtTmPkrWtr.Value;
    String query = "SELECT sno,currDate,WtrNm,Type,No FROM WtrTblAllot WHERE currDate = @SelectedDate";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedDate", new DateTime(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, selectedDate.Day, selectedDate.Hour, selectedDate.Minute, selectedDate.Second));
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    dgvWtrAllot.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: used your coding  same problem only database header without data @trippino

Comment: remove milliseconds from fields and query and retry (I've updated the answer in order to remove milliseconds). Think about to remove also seconds-minutes-hours if don't needed

Comment: For the query: use my updated answer, for the database: remove the 3 digits after the seconds (example: 2013-09-05 13:03:10.983 became 2013-09-05 13:03:10). Pay attention that DateTimePicker.Value gives the selected date with the current time, so I think that you should keep only the date part and remove the hour-minutes-seconds

Answer (score 0):

Use the bellow `code` to filter **data** in **`dataGridView`** by date, add this code to `ValueChanged` Event of `dateTimePicker` . I hope it will work :)

```
try
        {

            con = new SqlConnection(cs.ConDB);
            con.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT RTRIM(sno)as [sno],RTRIM(currDate) as [currDate],
            RTRIM(WtrNm) as [WtrNm],RTRIM(Type) as [Type],(No ) as [No] from WtrTblAllot where currDate like '" + currDate.Text + "%' order by currDate", con);
            SqlDataAdapter myDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet WtrTblAllot = new DataSet();
            myDA.Fill(WtrTblAllot , "WtrTblAllot ");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = WtrTblAllot .Tables["WtrTblAllot "].DefaultView;
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```